# Прописная буква в названиях, заключённых в кавычки из-за метаязыковой функции

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, кавычки, переводы

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли начинать словосочетание с прописной буквы, если того требует правило, но само словосочетание употребляется в кавычках из-за метаязыковой функции (в переводе)? Например:

*Японию часто называют Land of the Rising Sun, в переводе с английского — "(С/с)трана восходящего солнца".*

Знаю, что неформальные названия стран пишутся с прописной, но с точки зрения оформления перевода все подобные правила действуют или же нет? Другой пример для понимания:

*Американская компания Apple, в переводе — "(Я/я)блоко", является одним из мировых лидеров по производству смартфонов.*

Тут знаю, что названия компаний пишутся с прописной. Но распространяется ли это на слова и словосочетания, заключенные в кавычки из-за метаязыковой функции? Возникли сомнения. Надеюсь, вы меня поняли и поможете разобраться.

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (27.10.2023)**

"Грамота.ру" в итоге ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=311326)):

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Общую рекомендацию дать нельзя. Выбор написания будет предопределяться
> в каждом конкретном случае контекстом: в одном случае переводная фраза
> может осмысляться как название, в другом — как толкование значения. В
> первой приведенной Вами фразе видится возможным двоякое осмысление и,
> соответственно, написание: *Японию часто называют Land of the Rising
> Sun — Страна восходящего солнца* (название) и *Японию часто называют
> Land of the Rising Sun — «страна восходящего солнца»* (= что
> означает...). Во втором примере вводится переводное название, которое
> оформляется кавычками: *американская компания Apple (в переводе —
> «Яблоко»)*.

Comment: Не знаю, что вы понимаете под метаязыковой функцией, но все названия следует писать с прописной, в независимости от какой-то функции.

Comment: Имел в виду практику заключать в кавычки перевод слов.

Comment: При переводе действуют те же правила.

Comment: Пишите со строчной, раз у вас не название, а перевод слова/фразы, но и переводите дословно (слово "land").

Comment: Это название. Какая строчная?!

Comment: Shi, скажите, пожалуйста, вы этот вопрос задавали Грамоте тоже в июне, и она ответила только сейчас? Или вы несколько раз задавали? Я вот уже три недели не могу дождаться ответа (задавал два раза с промежутком в неделю).

Comment: Александр, я с ними работаю так: у меня копится и обновляется группа вопросов для "Грамоты.ру", я ей их все задаю в один день примерно 1-3 раза в неделю. На некоторые она отвечает буквально в тот же или на следующий день, а на некоторые (на которые я уже отчаялся получить ответ, но упорно задаю наравне с новыми вопросами) лишь спустя месяцы, а то и полгода бывает... Я думаю, что некоторые вопросы у них или просто теряются, или достаточно сложны, то есть они какое-то время их обдумывают (консультируются с кем-то, посылают запросы в ИРЯ РАН и пр.). Трясти их надо, видимо, чтобы ответили)))

Comment: Проще говоря, похоже, что чаще задавать им одни и те же вопросы = повышать шансы, что они на них вообще ответят.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Хороший у вас опыт с ними.